# authorisation based on values not on verb

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm implementing an authorisation process based on values not on verb.

Example:

- all **users/groups** are allowed to update a db field
- **admin** can set status to all possible values (confirmed | pending | cancelled)
- **supplier** can set to 'confirmed'

All examples I find go around a user/group being able or not to insert,update or delete something.

Is there something out there to deal with situations like this out of the box, or this has be hard coded?

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need is something hard to maintain in any application: granular permissions.

You can get this to work easily using Cartalyst's Sentry. Here's how I do it:

All my routes are hierarchically organized and named as such:

```
<?php

Route::get('login',      array('as'=>'logon.login',     'uses'=>'LogonController@login'));
Route::get('logged/out', array('as'=>'logon.loggedOut', 'uses'=>'LogonController@loggedOut'));

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('logout',     array('as'=>'logon.logout',    'uses'=>'LogonController@logout'));

    Route::group(array('before' => 'permissions'), function()
    {
        Route::get('store/checkout/shipping/address',   array('as'=>'store.checkout.shipping.address',  'uses'=>'StoreController@shippingAddress'));
        Route::get('store/checkout/payment/confirmed',  array('as'=>'store.checkout.payment.confirmed', 'uses'=>'StoreController@confirmed'));
        Route::get('profile',                           array('as'=>'profile.show',                     'uses'=>'ProfileController@show'));
    });
});
```

Those under the filter 'permissions' are subject to check if user has rights to use them:

```
Route::filter('permissions', function()
{
    $name = Route::current()->getName();
    $name =  'system' . ( ! empty($name) ? '.' : '') . $name;

    if (!Permission::has($name)) {
        App::abort(401, 'You are not authorized to access route '.$name);
    }
});
```

Basically here I get the current route name, add 'system.' to it and check if the user has this particular permission.

Here's how I create my groups and populate permissions:

```
<?php

public function seedPermissions()
{
    DB::table('groups')->truncate();

    $id = 1;

    Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
        'id' => $id++,
        'name'        => 'Super Administrators',
        'permissions' => array(
            'system' => 1,
        ),
    ));

    Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
        'id' => $id++,
        'name'        => 'Administrators',
        'permissions' => array(
            'system.users' => 1,
            'system.products' => 1,
            'system.store' => 1,
            'system.profile' => 1,
        ),
    ));

    Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
        'id' => $id++,
        'name'        => 'Managers',
        'permissions' => array(
            'system.products' => 1,
            'system.store' => 1,
            'system.profile' => 1,
        ),
    ));

    Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
        'id' => $id++,
        'name'        => 'Users',
        'permissions' => array(
            'system.store.checkout' => 1,
            'system.profile' => 1,
        ),
    ));
}
```

So if a user is trying to add some shipping address, the route 'store.checkout.payment.confirmed', as every user has access to 'system.store.checkout', everything inside that route will available to him.

And this is how I check for permissions:

```
public static function has($permission)
{
    $all = [];
    $parts = explode('.',$permission);
    $permission = '';

    foreach($parts as $part) {
        $permission .= (!empty($permission) ? '.' : '') . $part;
        $all[] = $permission;
    }

    return Sentry::check() and Sentry::getUser()->hasAnyAccess($all);
}
```

It basically builds a list of routes:

```
system
system.store
system.store.checkout
system.store.checkout.payment
system.store.checkout.payment.confirmed
```

And if Sentry finds one of those in the users granular permissions it will return true.

Now I just have to add users to groups:

```
Sentry::findUserById(1)->addGroup( Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findByName('Users') );
```

And if I need to go granular on a particular user/permission I just need to:

```
$user = Sentry::findUserById(1);
$user->permissions['store.checkout.payment'] = false;
$user->save();
```

And the user will never be able to pay for anything in the store again. :)

Comment: Thanks antonio. Need time to digest all this info. Going to dig more into this new term, granular permissions.